# Redeploy Segments option missing in Sitecore 8.2

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-xdb

I'm trying to fix an issue where the Sitecore marketing dashboard is throwing errors. The first suggestion in the kb and elsewhere is to go to localsitecore/sitecore/admin/RedeployMarketingData.aspx and select "Redeploy Segments" but that option isn't available. There is a section to Redeploy Maps, but not segments. I spun up an 8.1 version and the option is available. Did Sitecore move that to a new location in 8.2?